# pandas - return max value from a column with other column conditions

Tags: pandas, dataframe, max

I've been stuck on this for some time:
df =

```
Number Type  Year
421    MAN   2019
355    MAN   2019
644    SYS   2018
```

How can I return the maximum value where `Type` is `MAN` and `YEAR` is the maximum?

Here is my most recent attempt:

`max=max(list[df['Number'][df['Year']==2019 & df['Type']=='MAN'])`

Thanks in advance.

Expected `421`

Comment: shoot, i'm going to rephrase my question.

Comment: `df.loc[df.Year.eq(df.Year.max())&df.Type.eq('MAN'),'Number'].max()`

Comment: thanks you sir, pandas is so unintuitive to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
max=df[(df['Type']=='MAN') & (df['Year']=Max( df['Year']))]['Number']

print(max)
```

hope this helps,
Giulio

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Number":[421,355,644],"Type":["MAN","MAN","SYS"],"Year":[2019,2019,2018]})
selectedType = df[df["Type"] == "MAN"]
selectedTypeAndYear = selectedType.loc[selectedType["Year"] == selectedType["Year"].max(),:]
maxValue = selectedTypeAndYear["Number"].max()
```

My code is long because I want it to be understandable. I have tested the code and it works.